# How do I write this database comparison in Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql

Given databases x, y with matching schemas:

```
//for all entries in x.MY_TABLE
//        if PRIMARY_KEY of entry exists in y.MY_TABLE
//            if {data of entry in x} doesn't match {data of matching entry in y}
//                print PRIMARY_KEY
//        else
//            print PRIMARY_KEY
```

Assume that the table is a simple system with at most a 2-column primary key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want a list of all primary keys in `x` unless the key and data (i.e. the entire row) is the same. I think this should do it.

```
SELECT PRIMARY_KEY
FROM
(
SELECT * FROM x.MY_TABLE
MINUS
SELECT * FROM y.MY_TABLE
) T;
```

Comment: SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended

Comment: @deworde - I changed the `EXCEPT` that was originally there to `MINUS`

Comment: That's just an alias for the derived table defined inside the parentheses.